# Is there a way where I can make two side panels and additional test scripts in R utilizing Shiny?

Tags: r, shiny

Is there a way where I can make two "check boxes" within my Shiny App? One for selecting which "test" I want to conduct (etc. checking for null values, checking for duplicate values) and one for selecting which columns from my file I want to select for my test. The goal is to make a data quality application where I can select the fields I want to conduct various of data quality checks.
Also, how would I add additional tests, in my UI, such as checking for null values?

I am new to the Shiny package and would like some insights. Thank you!

Below is my code, currently I only have one test coded (checking for duplicate values):

```
library(shiny)
fp = 'C:/Users/WangE/Documents/DQA Test/'
library("readr")
library("dplyr")
library("tidyr")
library("data.table")
library("stringr")
library("RODBC")
library("openxlsx")
library("reshape")
library("readr")
library("ggplot2")
library("reshape2")
library("readxl")
library("varhandle") 
library("eeptools")
library("stringr")
options(scipen = 999)



TestData<-function(cols, data) {
 unique_checker <- cols
  duplicate_tracker <- list() 
  Other_Source_Total <- data %>% mutate_all(na_if, "")
  for(i in colnames(Other_Source_Total)){   
    if(toString(i) %in% unique_checker){   
      duplicate <- duplicated(tolower(Other_Source_Total[[i]])) | duplicated(tolower(Other_Source_Total[[i]]), fromLast = TRUE)
      Other_Source_Total$duplicate <- duplicate  
      duplicate_records <- Other_Source_Total  %>% filter(!is.na(Other_Source_Total[[i]])) %>% filter(duplicate == TRUE)
      if(NROW(duplicate_records != 0)){
        write.csv(duplicate_records, paste(fp,"Duplicate_Records_", str_remove(toString(i),'/'), ".csv", sep =""))
      }
      duplicate_tracker[[i]] <- NROW(duplicate_records)
    }
  }
  Other_Source_Total = subset(Other_Source_Total, select = -c(duplicate) ) 
  return(duplicate_tracker)
 
 } 


options(shiny.maxRequestSize = 900*1024^2)

ui <- pageWithSidebar(
  headerPanel("CSV Viewer"),
  sidebarPanel(
    fileInput('file1', 'Choose File',
              accept=c('text/csv', 'text/comma-separated-values,text/plain', '.csv')),
    tags$hr(),
    tags$head(),
    checkboxGroupInput("inCheckboxGroup",
                       "Checkbox group input:",
                       c()),
    uiOutput('choose_columns'),
    actionButton('doit','Do stuff')
  ),
  mainPanel(
    tableOutput('contents')
  )
)

server <- function(input, output,session) {
  dsnames <- c()
  
  data_set <- reactive({
    req(input$file1)
    inFile <- input$file1
    data_set<-read.csv(inFile$datapath, header=TRUE, sep=',')
  })
  output$contents <- renderTable({
    data_set()[1:min(length(data_set()),500),]
  })
  observe({
    req(input$file1)
    dsnames <- names(data_set())
    cb_options <- list()
    cb_options[ dsnames] <- dsnames
    updateCheckboxGroupInput(session, "inCheckboxGroup",
                             label = "Check Box Group",
                             choices = cb_options,
                             selected = "")
  })
  
  output$choose_dataset <- renderUI({
    req(input$Go)
    testVals<-selectInput("dataset", "Data set", as.list(data_sets))
  })
  
  # Check boxes
  output$choose_columns <- renderUI({
    # If missing input, return to avoid error later in function
    if(is.null(input$dataset))
      return()
    
    # Get the data set with the appropriate name
    
    colnames <- names(contents)
    
    # Create the checkboxes and select them all by default
    checkboxGroupInput("columns", "Choose columns", 
                       choices  = colnames,
                       selected = colnames)
  })
  
  observeEvent(input$doit, {
    value <- TestData(input$inCheckboxGroup,data_set())
    print(value)
  })
  
  
}
shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Below is a picture of the my UI:

[image here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0Exx6.png)

Answer (score 0):

I think the usual approach would be to use a multi-option select box to choose the columns to process (or displayed in the datatable). Refer to the "no choose prompt, multiple" example here: https://shiny.rstudio.com/gallery/selectize-vs-select.html.

There are a few ways to go about this but I’ve provided a working data-driven example of the controls and events that might help. In your case you would have a select or drop-down to choose the test, then in the server code it detects the event that a test has been selected and updates a multi-option select box that has column choices (using updateSelectInput). The selection of columns is also detected as an event in this example, and the data is updated for the datatable. There are other ways to update the datatable on the client without changing the data that others may suggest.

```r
library(shiny)
library(DT)

# global data only for example
ds <- list(faithful = datasets::faithful, iris = datasets::iris)

ui <- fluidPage(titlePanel("Select Example"),
                
                sidebarLayout(
                    sidebarPanel(
                        selectInput(
                            "sel_dataset",
                            "Options",
                            c("faithful", "iris"),
                            multiple = FALSE,
                            selectize = FALSE
                        ),
                        selectInput(
                            "sel_cols",
                            "Options",
                            NULL,
                            multiple = TRUE,
                            selectize = FALSE
                        )
                    ),
                    
                    mainPanel(dataTableOutput("dt_data"))
                ))

server <- function(input, output, session) {
    rv <- reactiveValues(dataset = NULL, cols = NULL)
    
    observeEvent(input$sel_dataset, {
        rv$dataset <- ds[input$sel_dataset][[1]]
        rv$cols <- colnames(rv$dataset)
        updateSelectInput(session,
                          "sel_cols",
                          choices = rv$cols,
                          selected = rv$cols)
    })
    
    observeEvent(input$sel_cols, {
        rv$cols <- input$sel_cols
    }, ignoreInit = TRUE)
    
    table_data <- reactive({
        if (!is.null(rv$cols)) {
            rv$dataset[, rv$cols, drop = FALSE]
        } else {
            rv$dataset
        }
    })
    
    output$dt_data = DT::renderDataTable({
        table_data()
    })
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Comment: Thank you for your advice on the mutli-selection option. I had an additional question that I would like your advice on. How would you go about adding additional test into the user interface? Right now, in the first line of code where I have my TestData set up, this is only checking for duplicate values. How would I add additional test, such as checking for null values? Would I need to add a for loop or an IF statement so that within my user interface, I am able to select both test and have an output for both test? Thank you again.